# JavaScript Loop Array and Make Boxes

Tags: javascript

```js
var x = document.getElementById("p");

var array = [
  ["Tino Kreutzer", " York University"],
  ["Prativa Baral", " York University"],
  ["Bobi Morris", " International Rescue Committee"],
  ["William Martin", " Catholic Relief Services"],
  ["Ruwan Rataynake", " London School of Hygiene & Tropical Medicine"]
];

var i;
var n;
for (i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; i++) {
  var column = document.createElement("div");
  column.className = "4u";
  var line = document.createElement("span");
  line.className = "nameCSS";
  var name = document.createTextNode(array[i][0]);
  line.appendChild(name);
  var line2 = document.createElement("span");
  line2.className = 'orgCSS';
  var org = document.createTextNode(array[i][1]);
  line2.appendChild(org);
  column.appendChild(line);
  column.appendChild(line2);
  x.appendChild(column);
};
```

```css
.line {
  font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="p">

  </div>
</body>
```

What's the easiest way to make div boxes with content like the following: https://ibb.co/G3JYdrL

What I'm trying to do is this but with array loops and createElements together:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="4u"><span>Name<br></span><span>Organization</span></div>
<div class="4u"><span>Name<br></span><span>Organization</span></div>
<div class="4u"><span>Name<br></span><span>Organization</span></div>  
<div class="4u"><span>Name<br></span><span>Organization</span></div>
<div class="4u"><span>Name<br></span><span>Organization</span></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Please read the tag excerpts when putting tags on your question. For instance, the excerpt for `jsfiddle` states: "For questions about using jsFiddle, a web application allowing users to create and execute code written in JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. DO NOT use this tag to indicate that your question contains a jsFiddle example."

Comment: *"Here's my current fiddle I'm working on"* Don't link to off-site resources. Instead, provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: What do you expect `column.className = "4u 12u$(small)";` to do? Because `12u$(small)` is not a valid class name.

Comment: `column.appendChild("line");` should be giving you an error in your web console. `line` != `"line"`.

Comment: It's not the problem (it could easily be the *next* problem), but: That code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Declare your variables in the appropriate scope (you havne't declared `i` or `n` anywhere). Not declaring them, in loose mode, makes them globals.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated my fiddle. column.className = "4u 12u$(small)" is a bootstrap class that I have in my theme. It's supposed to make a column 1/3 of the full width.

Answer (score 1):

Lots going on here but...

1. It should be `var column = document.createElement("div");`
2. It should be `column.appendChild(line);` and `column.appendChild(line2);`

beyond that, I have no idea what this should look like because several of your CSS classes are missing from the fiddle and your image link requires you to login to slack, which I do not have an account for and will not create one just for you.  Use imgur or something else that does not require an account.